# Transcoding media server streaming to the iPhone

Tags: video, iphone, streaming

I have a huge collection of videos in different formats, but with one thing in common: They are not playable on an iPhone (or iPod Touch). Instead of complaining about Apple's IMHO broken world view ("there are no video formats but quicktime and mp4"), I wonder if there's a solution out there that allows streaming these different videos to the iPhone.

This means that the source media needs to be transcoded on the fly.

I already tried a few solutions out there, but with varying success:

- [PS3 Media Server](http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/"PS3 Media Server") kind of worked, but only once and only for one single file.
- [TVersity](http://tversity.com/) is said to work, but it requires UAC to be disabled and I don't see any need for this.

The solution I'm looking for should run on Windows 2008 Server or Linux.

I just can't believe that there's nothing out there that would allow me to stream my huge video collection on my iPhone (we're talking Wifi here, not 3G).

---

After looking at the answers provided and after retrying TVersity without much success, I gave Orb another try and while the web interface failed to work for me, the iPhone Application (I tried the free one at first) actually worked flawlessly.

And not only that, it also manages to convert the streams on-the-fly, so you don't have to wait for the transcoding process to finish before playback starts.

On my 2.26 Ghz MacMini Server, this worked even with 1080p material.

For Windows 2008 Server users out there: Remember to install the Desktop Experience Feature in the Server Manager if you intend this to work.

Of all the stuff I had a look at, this really provided instant-success - even though I'm now probably sending the contents of my harddrive to orb's central server (*sigh*)

Comment: Does anyone have any linux options? This would be a nice feature to have on my HTPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Air Video HD is good for this. They have servers for Linux, Windows and Mac and an accompanying iPhone app.

Link: http://www.inmethod.com/airvideohd/index.html

Comment: I agree. it's the best solution these days. I'm using it since forever now.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Orb in a while, but had great success with it on my XBox 360 before Microsoft supported Xxid, and it looks like they now support transcoding to an iPhone:

http://www.orb.com/en/orblive

Comment: I did try orb, but the moment they wanted me to log in to their website so I could stream my media locally, I gave up. I will give this another shot later today though.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that - I had a great experience with them, though, and you can even stream live TV locally / over 3G if you have a cable tuner.

Answer (score 0):

Twonky-vision has a plugin based transcoder it requires a bit of user engineering to make things work - but it should be able to at the very least serve your content to you via a http server.

It'll act as a super DLNA server for all your devices that don't have sucky format support :)

Answer (score 0):

I run TVersity on Windows Server 2008 without any issues whatsoever. I use it to stream to my X-Box 360, Windows 7 and MacOSX Clients with UAC not disabled.

Comment: Installing it without UAC was definitely not possible for me. Even after turning it off and completing the installation, I didn't manage to get anything out of TVErsity but errors in the log file.

I don't doubt it works for you. It didn't for me though.